# How to change require statements inline using codemod (jscodeshift)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, jscodeshift, codemod

Hi I'm trying to write a codemod which moves my require statement from top of the file to inside class constructor function.

```
const moduleA = require('moduleA');
const moduleB = require('../moduleB');

class Example {
  constructor(context) {
    this.lazy(
      "moduleA",
      () => new moduleA(context)
    );
    this.lazy(
      "moduleB",
      () => new moduleB(context)
    );
  }
  
  lazy() {
  
  }

  async callThis() {
     this.moduleA.callThatMethod();
  }
}

module.exports = Example;
```

These require statements on top of the file taking long time, which is only used if that API is called at-least once. So as the require is being cached by Node.js at process level anyway. I'm trying to move the `require` statement inside the arrow function.

Like Below

```
class Example {
  constructor(context) {
    super(context);
    this.lazy("moduleA", () => { 
       const moduleA = require('moduleA');
       return new moduleA() 
    }
    this.lazy("moduleB", () => {
      const moduleB = require('../moduleB');
      return new moduleB() 
    }
  }

  async callThis() {
     this.moduleA.callThatMethod();
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble achieving this, because i dunno how to select the "lazy" function defined and then move the top require.

Any help is much appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need **jscodeshift** for such a simple transformation. With my tool [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) you can easily remove top-level `require`, and add it to `lazy` function:

```js
const isTopLevel = (vars, {parentPath}) => parentPath.isProgram();

export const match = () => ({
    'const moduleA = require("moduleA")': isTopLevel,
    'const moduleB = require("../moduleB")': isTopLevel,
});

export const replace = () => ({
    'const moduleA = require("moduleA")': '',
    'const moduleB = require("../moduleB")': '',
    '() => new moduleA(context)': `{
        const moduleA = require("moduleA");
        return new moduleA();
    }`,
    '() => new moduleB(context)': `{
        const moduleA = require("../moduleB");
        return new moduleB();
    }`,
});
```

[Try it](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/f4e5cb376621176afae24d7d9f8773dc/e2277c1b92c05cbc267f6d86b06bc14ec61f5ef7)

[image: putout editor]

If you need to filter out `this.lazy` and have a lot of different modules, you can use [**PutoutScript**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/blob/master/docs/putout-script.md#-putoutscript) with template values `__a` and `__b` used to determine and replace `Identifier` from `VariableDeclarator` `id` and `StringLiteral` from `CallExpression` `callee` inside `VariableDeclarator` `init` in `const moduleA = require('moduleA')` `VariableDeclaration`:

> ☝️ This language is what you **HAVE TO** deal with while using **jscodeshift** all the time

```js
const isTopLevel = ({parentPath}) => parentPath.isProgram();

export const match = () => ({
    // filter out cases where require path contains name
    'const __a = require(__b)': ({__a, __b}, path) => {
        
        if (!isTopLevel(path))
            return false;
        
        // ☝️ __a: Identifier & {name: string}
        // ☝️ __b: StringLiteral & {value: string};
        return __b.value.includes(__a.name);
    },
    
    // filter out 'this.lazy'
    '() => new __a(context)': ({__a}, path) => {
        // ☝️ parentPath: CallExpression & {callee: MemberExpression}
        return compare(path.parentPath.node.callee, 'this.lazy');
    }
});

export const replace = () => ({
    // remove top-level require according to 'match'-condition'
    'const __a = require(__b)': '',
    
    // insert 'require'
    '() => new __a(context)': ({__a}) => {
        return `() => {
            const __a = require("${__a.name}");
            return new __a();
        }`
    },
});
```

[Try it](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/ccbdeff7d55f96396ce1db53b6162840/26227b386d37243f631c5a0dc509051a383386de)

[image: putout editor]

> - *☝️ **Putout** based on [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) has powerful declarative API and lots of [built-in transformations](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout#-built-in-transformations).*
> - *☝️ Tired of writing long rolls of code  [check out code transformers comparison](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout#%EF%B8%8F-in-doubt-about-using-putout).*